# Bootstrap card footer to move up and down with sliding animation

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am using the below card, and inside it, there is a search box, when the user clicks on search box it provides the user with some suggestion which is basically a list. When this list is displayed the card footer moves down (without animation) and when I clear the suggestion list the footer jumps up (without animation). How can I add animation at both points when it moves up and down, my code is in Vue.js and I tried transition option but that didn't work.

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    This is Header
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
   <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    This is footer
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

After entering in the search box, it gives you the suggestion which causes the footer to moves down

[image]

Using this code for populating my suggestion list array which I call filteredLoggersList[],  loggersListInit.allLevels is basically a JSON of the array which is an unfiltered list of loggers. The below codes basically filter the array based on what user types in search box.

```
filteredLoggers() {
      if (this.searchData != "") {
        this.filteredLoggersList = this.loggersListInit.allLevels.filter(
          log => {
            return log.name
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(this.searchData.toLowerCase());
          }
        );
      } else {
        this.filteredLoggersList = [];
      }
    },
```

Comment: How is the list of suggestions being populated? The code which does that would be a good spot to animate the footer opening. Likewise, you need code to listen for the suggestion box being set to a blank string, and when it detects that it animates the footer closing.

Comment: @kmoser I have updated my question

Comment: give `position: absolute` to suggestion box